Why is my USB 3.0 SD card reader from Amazon being detected as USB 2.0?
I have a Dell Inspiron 15-3567 running Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS.  When I plug in my USB 3.0 SD card reader in a USB 3.0 port in my laptop, it is being detected as USB 2.0. The reader has a 9 pin USB A male connector.
It is a pretty cheap reader from Amazon from a brand named "Digitek"; the exact model is DIGITEK® (DCR 006) USB 3.0 High Speed 2 in 1 Multi Card Reader.
It was explicitly claimed on Amazon's product page that is was USB 3.0 and capable of speeds up to 5Gbps.
They claim the same on the brand's official site:

"Support Super-Speed (5Gbps), High Speed (480Mbps) & Full Speed(12 Mbps)"


I know that the port in my laptop is working fine as I've tried it with an external HDD, and it detects it correctly.

Could there be any underlying issue for this or have I just been scammed into buying a USB 2.0 reader?

There is one review on that Amazon listing by  "Gayatri D." stating: it is detected as USB 2.0 CRW and it is actually a USB 2.0 device fakely marked as 3.0 on the package in at least 5 places. Even the USB port has been made blue in color to mimic a 3.0 port. The data transfer speeds I got was about 27MBps for sequential read operation on a USB 3.0 port and other users have reported similar speeds confirming it is a USB 2.0 device

@rene I should have refrained from buying it after seeing the speeds in the reviews, but I gave it the benefit of doubt of it being the result of the cards itself, I didn't expect them to blatantly lie about the specification all over the product page.

Yeah, I'm sorry you have this experience.

There is of course another possibility... there could indeed be a product from that manufacturer with the claimed specifications.  But you might have received a counterfeit, not made by the genuine manufacturer, and possibly not even coming from the seller whom you chose to purchase from.  Even when "Fulfilled by Amazon".  Important search term: commingled inventory

"I didn't expect them to blatantly lie about the specification all over the product page." - This happens all the time for cheap crap from Amazon, Ebay, AliExpress, etc.

You likely are another scam victim on Amazon.
From personal experience, I can tell you that many product descriptions on Amazon are either completely false or incredibly misleading.  If you search the internet, you can see many others have the same experience.
My advice is to try returning the product to Amazon.  Do it quickly though.  I also have personal experience with Amazon not honouring their posted return policy.
I don't want to use this space to recommend other stores, but I strongly recommend finding a better place to purchase products instead of Amazon.  A store with a physical presence is typically a good sign.

The problem with products on Amazon is that Amazon doesn’t verify the product descriptions, of course they don’t have the ability to verify every single product description, so I make a habit of looking at the manufacturer websites.

@Ramhound Not only does it appear Amazon doesn't verify product descriptions, I've witnessed many cases where Amazon doesn't fix patently false product descriptions even when multiple people have pointed out Amazon's false information.  Given their profits, Amazon actually does have the monetary resources to review every product description; Amazon willfully chooses not to do so.

@Ramhound They also are known to mix stock from multiple sellers, which means that just checking the manufacturer website is not reliably enough to ensure you don’t get a scam product.

You're right, and I also think I've found the controller being used in this product and it does infact only support USB 2.0 https://www.genesyslogic.com.tw/en/product_view.php?show=72

Amazon has agreed to a refund upon returning the product. For me personally, Amazon.in has been pretty generous with the return policy, I've returned products that didn't come with an option to return. The real pain is getting the Amazon dumb bot to connect me to a human agent

@EndAntisemiticHate: Amazon does have the monetary resources to review every product description; - IDK if I'd go that far.  It's probably technically true, but wouldn't be a smart way to spend that amount of money.  Presumably penalties for sellers for too many false descriptions would go a long way, plus random spot-checks.  (And a penalty scalar where the nature and severity of the false claim is taken into account, considering both likelihood of intentional fraud vs. honest mistake and of how much worse it makes the product for the consumer.)  I assume there's basically no penalty now?

@PeterCordes: There is no penalty because the scammers are typically not real companies, they are pseudonymous shell companies that appear and disappear as needed to evade consequences for their actions (hence why brand names on Amazon are often nonsense words - it is probably a Markov chain or something of that nature churning out plausible-ish brands).

@Ramhound not always sufficient. I've been fake products advertised that were listed as being from a major manufacturer, including real product number and photos taken from the manufacturer website but were actually cheap Chinese knockoffs. ALWAYS check the seller/vendor and if it's not Amazon themselves or a known good partner (and even then be suspicious) assume it's a scam product from some Chinese drop shop.

@LeonRaj ?I have the same experience with Amazon. They're pretty good at handling returns, especially if the product wasn't as advertised.

Remember that Amazon have a mix of products they sell themselves and products sold by third parties ("marketplace"). Products sold by Amazon are usually fine, and returns/refunds on those are rarely an issue. For third parties, it can be quite different. In the middle you have products from third parties "shipped by" Amazon, which are usually more trustworthy than the ones shipped directly by third parties. Sometimes for a same product there may be a mix, and unscrupulous sellers may "latch on" a real good product and sell a very different one. Always check the "Sold by" before buying.

@PeterCordes - So they review every product description how do they verify it’s actually accurate? They can’t verify every single thing individual product with a human.

@Ramhound: Yeah EndAntisemiticHate's suggestion of that didn't seem reasonable  to me, either.  Only something that might be theoretically possible with a huge workforce.  And only plausible up to some level of diligence like checking manufacturer specs, since actually physically getting hands on with every product is not even plausible.

Return it. If for some reason you can't return it, hopefully you used a credit card; file a claim under your card's consumer protections. Blatant product misrepresentation is illegal, and while it's probably not worth your time to pursue a legal claim, it's also usually not worth it to a company like Amazon to fight a charge-back.

About the only thing I can recommend getting on Amazon is what the company started out with: books. Especially if you're looking for books in original English whilst living in a non-English speaking country, then Amazon has the best prices and a huge selection. But for everything else best look for local stores with physical locations, preferably.

Even though you have already gotten your answer (you've been scammed), I see a couple of common misconceptions in your question that I would like to address. You write [bold italic emphasis mine]:

It is a pretty cheap reader from Amazon

Actually, it is not "from Amazon". It is from Clicktech Retail Private Ltd.

It was explicitly claimed on Amazon's product page

Same as before: it's not "Amazon's product page", it is Clicktech's.
You didn't buy the reader from Amazon, you bought it from a third-party seller on Amazon Marketplace.
Amazon Marketplace is an offering by Amazon where third-parties can sell products, both used or new. Compare that to Amazon, where only Amazon sells products and only new products.
There are several different models for third-parties to sell on Amazon (Marketplace) which further influence how much involvement Amazon has:

Amazon Vendor: vendors who sell through the Amazon Vendor program sell their products to Amazon wholesale, and Amazon then re-sells those products through Amazon proper. The Amazon Vendor program is invite-only, i.e., Amazon Vendors need to be invited by Amazon.

Amazon Seller: sellers in the Amazon Seller program sell their products on the Amazon Marketplace. They sell directly to the buyer, without involving Amazon. Amazon merely provides the Amazon Marketplace infrastructure and payment processing. This means, in particular, Amazon has no control over the quality of the products nor the veracity of the product descriptions.
There are two different options for Amazon Sellers how to handle fulfillment of the sale:

Fulfilled by Seller: the seller is responsible for all stages of fulfillment, sending out order confirmations, packing, shipping, customer service, inventory management, logistics, etc. The seller ships the product directly to the buyer. Amazon never touches the product.
Fulfilled by Amazon: Amazon is responsible for all stages of fulfillment. The seller only needs to ship their inventory to one of Amazon's centers, and Amazon takes care of inventory management, logistics, packing, shipping, as well as customer service.



In your case, you bought the reader from a Seller on Amazon Marketplace. You didn't buy from Amazon nor did you buy from an Amazon Vendor.
You are in luck, though, because it looks like the seller is using the Fulfilled by Amazon program, which means Amazon is responsible for customer service. If the seller were using the Fulfilled by Seller program, then your customer service request would have gone to the same person who scammed you in the first place! Which probably would not have been very fruitful.

Thanks for the detailed explanation. But it was implied as in buying from the Amazon website, not much of a misconception, just a common way of saying it. Amazon used to sell a lot of stuff under Cloudtail and Appario but they were forced to sell a part of their stake in those companies to Clicktech due to some government policy changes. Even though Amazon can't verify each product page, there should be an easy way to report products on Amazon, when I asked customer support how I can report the seller they said that "they'll share the feedback to the seller".

Amazon deliberately doesn't do anything about scammers because they know it'll affect their revenue, amd there's nothing much Amazon could do either to be fair, if they ban a seller, they'd just come up with another shell company. And in my particular case, it's not the seller's fault, as we can see "digitek" is the one making the false claims on their official site, and the seller took their word for it. But I'm sure the seller wouldn't do a thing even if they knew.

@LeonRaj Amazon does a lot about scammers, if they get notified about one. Problem is that the scammers can create hundreds of new fake storefronts in the time it takes Amazon to discover and remove a single one.

"Fulfilled by Seller" is commonly called "Fulfilled by Merchant" or FBM. In both FBM and FBA, the merchant is required to respond to customer complaints lodged via the Amazon site, and is continuously evaluated by Amazon's systems on complaint count, promptness of response, etc. It's easy to lose merchant status if the indicators fall too low, and the indicators themselves are not visible to the merchant. So -- in theory -- the merchant is motivated to always refund to preserve status, even in cases where a customer's complaint is unreasonable.

I usually batch my shopping on amazon, then shipping costs increase when the order is fulfilled from several places (and possibly the expected delivery date also changes), that is typically clue enough that I'm about to do something stupid - I generally continue looking if I see a product that is not sold (or at least fulfilled) by amazon.

"Compare that to Amazon, where only Amazon sells products and only new products." unfortunately in recent years, Amazon have made it very difficult to filter to only products they themselves sell. They deliberately blur the line between retailer and marketplace site.

If Amazon doesn't to a scam product complain they just get hit with chargebacks. Contacting seller is clearly fruitless and there's no reason to do so.

@jwenting they do actually absolutely nothing about scammers. They don't even bother fixing completel wrong product descriptions reported to them - e.g. a random white part sold as inflatable electric stadium pillow: https://www.amazon.pl/gp/product/B0CN6HCC9C/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1 This was reported to them throght their report functionality, product opinions and customer service by multiple people, yet they didn't do shit, it can still be sold. They somehow allow mainly Chinese scammers to do way worse service than on AliExpress, Temu or anything alike.
